# Inferring the addends of the sum of two random variables

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian

I have three independent Poisson variables: B, C and D, whose parameters $\lambda_B$, $\lambda_C$ and $\lambda_D$ are unknown.

I sample once the variable:
$$
A_1 \equiv 0.9\cdot B + 0.1\cdot C
$$
and I get the result: $ A_1 = a_1 $.

$A_1$ is the sum of two Poissonian distributions and therefore it is Poissonian as well.
On the basis of this I make an estimate of $ \lambda_{A_1} $: $ \hat\lambda_{A_1} = a_1 $ and the variance of the estimator $ \hat\lambda_{A_1} $ is $ \sigma_{\hat\lambda_{A_1}}^2 = a_1 $.

Thereafter, I sample once the variable:
$$
A_2 \equiv 0.9\cdot B + 0.1\cdot D
$$
and I get the result: $ A_2 = a_2 $.

Now in principle I should estimate: $ \hat\lambda_{A_2} = a_2 $ and $ \sigma_{\hat\lambda_{A_2}}^2 = a_2 $ as before.

But isn't it possible to get an estimator $ \hat\lambda_{A_2} $ with a smaller variance than $ a_2 $, exploiting the result of the first sampling of $ A_1 $, seen that $ A_1 $ and $ A_2 $ have in common the addend $ 0.9\cdot B $ ? Maybe applying some Bayes's theory ?

My goal is to estimate $A_2$ with a small estimator's variance. I am not interested in B, C and D.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma_{\hat\lambda_{A_1}}^2 = a_1$? The variance of the estimator is a function of the parameters, not the data. And what do you mean by "a smaller variance"? The variance of $\hat\lambda_{A_2}$ likewise depends on the parameters, and since you haven't specified a prior for the parameters, there's no expected variance that could be considered "the" variance.

Comment: joriki, you are right: my question is ill-posed.I said $ \sigma^2_{\hat\lambda_{A_1}} = a_1$, but actually is $ {\hat\sigma}^2_{\lambda_{A_1}} = a_1$, because I had the Poisson variable $ A_1$ and I sampled it once, getting $A_1 = a_1$. On the basis of this only one sample I estimate $ \hat\lambda_{A_1} = a_1$ ($ \hat\lambda_{A_1}$ is the estimator of $\lambda_{A_1}$) and ${\hat\sigma}^2_{A_1} = a_1$. The same goes for the sampling of $A_2$: $A_2 = a_2$, so $ \hat\lambda_{A_2} = a_2$. Now, what is the variance of $ \hat\lambda_{A_2} $, and can I use the result of the 1. sampling to reduce it ?